# jQuery AJAX submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This jQuery code submits a form using AJAX. The server response should return JSON.

```
addNewOutreach = function(node)
    {
    var form = node.find('form');
    var data = form.serialize();

    $.post('ajax.php',
    {action:'addNewOutreach',string:data},
    function(response) {
        if(response!=null && response.status=='success')
            {
            message_return('success',response.message);
            unfreezeModal(node);
            node.modal('hide');
            }
        else if(response!=null && response.status=='error')
            {
            message_return('error',response.message);
            unfreezeModal(node);
            }
        else 
            {
            message_return('error','Error saving outreach.');
            unfreezeModal(node);
            }
        },'json');
    }
```

`message_return()` is a function that displays feedback on the page.

`unfreezeModal()` is a function that locks the form (avoiding double submits) until the request is finished.

Where this code lacks:

- What if the server does not respond with valid JSON?
- What if the AJAX request keeps hanging?
- The `function(response)` block can probably be isolated from this block so it can be used in other AJAX request
- Can probably be written cleaner with Promises

Answer (score 1):

1. You should first check if the response is null. If not, then check for a success or error response.
2. You can use a `try`-`catch` block to check if it is valid JSON:

   ```
   Try{
       JSON.parse(response);
       catch(Exception){
       console.log("Not valid json");
       handle();
   }
   ```
3. If what you are expecting from the server to be in a constant format you could use the callback code again and again in different functions.

Comment: Thanks, but more looking for something like promise.done() and promise.then(). Try/Catch seems old, no?